# Zeppelin hbase interpreter installation fails to resolve dependencies

Tags: maven, installation, hbase, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to install the zeppelin interpreter for hbase 1.1.4 on a cluster.

I tried the basic interpreter installation command for hbase:

```
/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/bin/install-interpreter.sh --name hbase
```

And I got this error message:

```
[root@zeppelinHost/]# /usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/bin/install-interpreter.sh --name hbase
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/zeppelin/lib/interpreter/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/zeppelin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Install hbase(org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-hbase:0.7.0) to /usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/interpreter/hbase ...
org.sonatype.aether.RepositoryException: Cannot fetch dependencies for org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-hbase:0.7.0
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.getArtifactsWithDep(DependencyResolver.java:181)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.loadFromMvn(DependencyResolver.java:131)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:79)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:96)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:88)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.install(InstallInterpreter.java:172)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.install(InstallInterpreter.java:136)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.install(InstallInterpreter.java:128)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.main(InstallInterpreter.java:280)
```

I'm trying to understand what is causing the dependency resolution failure.

> Note that the cluster is behind a corporate proxy.

According to the [docs](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/interpreter/hbase.html):

> By default, Zeppelin is built against HBase 1.0.x releases. To work
> with HBase 1.1.x releases, use the following build command:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -P build-distr -Dhbase.hbase.version=1.1.4 -Dhbase.hadoop.version=2.6.0
```

So perhaps the problem will be solved by running this `mvn clean package + options` but I have several questions.

- Is the `mvn clean package + options` command meant to be run directly on the Zeppelin host on the cluster? If yes:

  - What are the possible consequences? What will happen to my current zeppelin installation and config?
  - Is it possible to backup my current zeppelin installation and config to roll back to if the suggested `mvn clean package + options` doesn't work as expected
- Is the dependency resolution failure not related to this? Is it potentially due to the corporate proxy?
- Is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that the interpreter download is failing due to the [Issue documented here](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334). Zeppelin by default is using http (which has been deprecated) instead of https to access Sonatype repos. Looks like the [Zeppelin ticket to fix this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-4566?jql=project%20%3D%20ZEPPELIN%20AND%20text%20%7E%20%22Cannot%20fetch%20dependencies%22) is still open.

In short the workaround is to add this line to zeppelin-env.sh.

```
export ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_DEP_MVNREPO="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
```

Your interpreter install should then work :)